# You are authenticated as allaye, but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?

Tags: django, django-models

so i am trying to update my user profile, the login and registration works well, but when i try to update the user profile it does not work and i dont receive any error. after updating when i try to access the django admin page i get the about error message. let say i login into the admin page as boss which is a super user, and into my app as gate, after updating gate details when i try to access the admin page with had already been loged in by boss, i get the about error message. below are my code.

```
/views.py

def signin(request):
    form = UserLogin(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})


@login_required()
def profile(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=request.user)
        form = UserDetailsUpdate(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('profile')
    form = UserDetailsUpdate(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})

/models.py

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

/forms.py


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    sex = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class UserDetailsUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('image', 'website', 'sex')

class UserLogin(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

Comment: `request.user` is an instance of `User` not an instance of `UserProfile` (which is the model your form is for).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so how do I get the instance of Userprofile that corresponds with the User?

Answer (score 0):

As Abdul mentioned in the comments, `request.user` is an instance of `django.contrib.auth.User`, so the form would try to save to the User instead of saving into the UserProfile.

To access your user profile having only the User instance, you can use its "backwards" relationship. That is defined using the `related_name` in the ForeignKey (OneToOneField in your case) declaration.

In your case, because the `related_name` is not explicitly declared, the default value is the class name in lowercase: `user.userprofile`.

You can read more about Django relationships here:

[OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

[ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)